# when i build a encoder model,show me __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: keras, arguments, typeerror, tensorflow2.0, init

```
class Image_encoder(keras.Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(Image_encoder,self).__init__()
    
    self.fc1=layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.fc2=layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, padding='same')
def call(self,inputs):
    x=self.fc1(inputs) #1
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)#2
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)#3
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)#4
    x=self.fc2(x)
    x=self.fc1(x)#5
    x=self.fc2(x)
    return tf.squeeze(x)
g=Image_encoder(x_train_query_dataset)
```

x_train_query_dataset is <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 28, 28, 1), dtype=float32，numpy=……>

when i ran the code, it showed me the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Self parameter represents a particular instance of a class and is used to access variables of that instance. Now since you're passing `x_train_query_dataset` in the object of your class, this means your class should also expect this variable in the definition. But it does not take any parameters in your `init` definition. Hence, it throws a `TypeError: init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

You can resolve this by adding  this parameter in `init`

```
class Image_encoder(keras.Model):
def __init__(self, x_train_query_dataset):
    super(Image_encoder,self).__init__() # Add arguments super class is expecting, if any.

g=Image_encoder(x_train_query_dataset)
```